Can one produce Pantone Metallics with LaTeX?
The queston is: Can one produce Pantone Metallics with LaTeX? And how?
We have been looking at the three packages: colorspace, spotcolor and xespotcolor and they all seem to define the Pantone colors via (or using) the CMYK values. An example from the colorspace package is:
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE7497PC} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 7497\SpotSpace PC} {0.4 0.3 0.7 0.25}

Acoording to the experts, there is no true CMYK equivalent for the Metallics, and to achieve a metallic silver or gold effect, you need to use a dedicated Pantone metallic spot color ink, as standard CMYK printing cannot accurately replicate the metallic sheen of a silver finish.

Spot colors are colors that are pre-mixed. You need to tell the printing machine to use this color, so PDFs can do that. Of course, a printer that only supports CMYK or a computer with a RGB screen cannot directly reproduce such a color. It is, however, possible to simulate such colors by converting the spot color to a process color. How you convert one to another is more or less up to you. Of course, you can't replicate the metallic effect with just CMYK or RGB. So, here as well, you need to approximate.

To achieve a "realistic" metallic effect, however, you can't just convert the color. You will need to use other methods, such as using gradients or substituting the colored area with an image. There is no easy way to do this and it is up to you to choose a way to do this which relates to the specific output you need.

@JasperHabicht but if a PDF can tell the printer to use a particular kind of colour, isn't the question whether there's a package which enables that to be specified in the document? of course, whether the screen and/or printer correctly render the result is a question of hardware, but whether there's a package which makes it easy to request the hardware do it is a reasonable one. likewise, what else is needed to achieve a particular effect is another question again.

@cfr You are right, I probably understood the OP's question wrong. It seems in fact not too easy to select spot colors using one of the common packages for colors. But it seems the l3colors package does support spot colors.

@JasperHabicht could you provide a link to l3colors. I have not heard of this package yet, neither does CTAN.

@TeXApprentice It is part of the latex3 kernel and as such its documentation is part of interfaces3. But actually, having looked into that, I wondered whether spot colors are really supported ... at least you can make use of \color_model_new:nnn probably ...

None of the packages define spotcolors in terms of cmyk. The cmyk value is a (required) fallback needed to view the PDF on a monitor.
With l3color (which is a part of the kernel) you can define and use a spotcolor like this. This needs the PDF management that you load with \DocumentMetadata:
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \color_model_new:nnn { metallic } { Separation }
    {
      name = Pantone~Metallics , %use your name
      alternative-model = cmyk ,
      alternative-values = {1, 0.56, 0,0},
    }
 \color_set:nnn{metallic1}{metallic}{1}
 \cs_set_eq:NN\colorselect\color_select:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\colorselect{metallic1} some spotcolor


\end{document}


Where does the metallic color name, "Pantone 877 C" for example, goes into?

where I wrote Pantone~Metallics

It works!!! Ulrike, where can I check the manual for it? Is this a replacement for all these other packages?

the l3color commands are documented in interface3.pdf

How does one make it work with packages that require, for example, xcolor?

One of these packages is bookcover where the colors defined in this way do not work.

Such a great suggestion, hats off

@TeXApprentice Some problems with tikz are described in https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb43-2/tb134fischer-spotcolor.pdf. I have an open issue about that at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1244 - you could add a comment that this affects you too ...

@UlrikeFischer, I added it there, even though the thread seems to be explicit about PGF and my problem seems to be about compatibility with xcolor.

@TeXApprentice I can not change xcolor and merge it with l3color to support properly spotcolors as that would break tikz which relies on internals. tikz has to change its implementation first.

colorspace is mostly superseded by l3color. (Note: I’m the author of colorspace.)
